# Extending NX generate component

Tags: angular, nrwl-nx, angular-schematics

In my Monorepo, there are two types of components that i am using.

1. Is a standard component for applications, and `nx g c foo` works fine here.
2. Is a library component for a library. Here, I exclusively use secondary entry points. So a component always has an index.ts, a public_api.ts, a bar.module.ts and a package.json file.

My question is, how could I extend the standard functionality of the `nx g c foo`, so that it automatically creates these files?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably want to write your own schematics collection.
Please check [documentation](https://angular.io/guide/schematics), [some](https://indepth.dev/posts/1438/extend-angular-schematics-to-customize-your-development-process) [nice](https://blog.angular.io/schematics-an-introduction-dc1dfbc2a2b2) [articles](https://tomastrajan.medium.com/total-guide-to-custom-angular-schematics-5c50cf90cdb4) and [sources](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/blob/master/packages/schematics/angular/component/index.ts).
Basically your extending code from new component schematic will look like this:

```
import { chain, externalSchematic, Rule } from '@angular-devkit/schematics';

export default function(schema: any): Rule {
    // add your custom code here

    return chain([
        externalSchematic('@nrwl/schematics', 'module', {
          ...module options
        }),
        externalSchematic('@nrwl/schematics', 'component', {
          ...component options
        }),

        // and here
    ]);
}
```

UPD

The same written using nx generators API:

```
import { wrapAngularDevkitSchematic } from '@nrwl/devkit/ngcli-adapter';
import {
  Tree,
  formatFiles,
  generateFiles,
  joinPathFragments,
  names,
} from '@nrwl/devkit';
// this is your custom generator schema
import { Schema } from './models/schema.model';

export default async function (tree: Tree, schema: Schema) {
  const moduleGenerator = wrapAngularDevkitSchematic(
    '@schematics/angular',
    'module'
  );
  const componentGenerator = wrapAngularDevkitSchematic(
    '@schematics/angular',
    'component'
  );

  // it will create a custom module for you
  await moduleGenerator(tree, {
    name: ...module name,
    project: ...project to add module,
    path: ...path to add module file,
  });

  // it will create a custom component for you
  await componentGenerator(tree, {
    name: ...your name,
    project: ...project to add component,
  });

  // it's a branch where you can add your package.json and index.ts
  // you should create template files for them in ./files folder
  generateFiles(
    tree, // the virtual file system
    joinPathFragments(__dirname, './files'), // path to the file templates
    joinPathFragments('libs/'), // destination path of the files
    {
      ...schema,
      ...names(schema.name),
      tmpl: '',
    } // config object to replace variable in file templates
  );


  return tree;
}
```

See their [tests](https://github.com/nrwl/nx/blob/b8162c4a17be7de1e5ac394b52720af43fcf0ac4/packages/angular/src/generators/utils/testing.ts) for more examples.

Comment: Thx for answering. Just to clarify. Your solution would solely work with angular schematics, right? I might misunderstand nx, but I thought that nx would enable someone me to write schematics that can be used anywhere in the project. I'm not sure, but I think this is what @nrwl/nx-plugins is used for.

Comment: See this link https://nx.dev/latest/angular/generators/using-schematics. No, angular schematics (like nx generators) are just code generation tools so it will work for any js/ts based project. But yes, API for nx plugins is slightly different. Updated the answer

Comment: Thank you very much for the excellent answer. I was able to solve my problem and generally understand the whole topic a lot better.

Comment: Posting a link to a paid article?  Is this allowed?

Comment: @code I believe it wasn't under paywall when I posted it. Removed the link.